# Can you prevent std::regex from throwing exception on invalid expressions?

Tags: c++, regex, std

```
std::regex regex("*", std::regex_constants::icase);
```

This will throw an exception. If I have exceptions *disabled*, it will terminate the application, and that means I **cannot** catch it and do nothing with it like I normally would do.

Is there anyway to prevent invalid regex from throwing exceptions when it is constructed? Or some kind of `std::regex::isvalid("*")` check that exists?

I was thinking maybe I could come up with a separate regex that parses the input regex expression string before I attempt the constructor, but I would much prefer an alternative.

Comment: does simply not catching the exception and doing nothing with it fit your requirements?

Comment: @Blondie No. When exceptions are disabled, you can't just catch the exception. You literally can't even throw the exception

Comment: You can't parse a regex with a regex.

Comment: Do you really need to use regex?

Comment: @revo No you can't, but you can use a regex to parse a string before I use it as a regex.

Comment: That's the same thing I just commented on. Naming it *string* doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @KillzoneKid - Are there any alternatives that support expression searches that isn't a lib outside of the std? std::find is not only too simple, it's far too slow for my use case.

Comment: In the moment that you disabled exceptions, you are not using standard C++ anymore. In that case, you should probably specify your compiler and architecture. Maybe there's a compiler-specific solution, but there can't be a standard one, by definition.

Comment: The source is compiled across multiple compilers and architectures, so any compiler specific solution (if one exists) would be insufficient for me sadly. =(

Comment: @revo - I thought you misunderstood my intent. I see what you're saying now.

Comment: @user99999991 `std::string` has own set of nice string manipulators, there is no reason to use generic `std::find`. But answering this without knowing exactly what you need is pointless.

Comment: Like I said, expression searches. Sorry if that's not a real phrase, I mean like pattern matching, substring searches, all in one. "Lorum Ipsum 1, 2, 3" - match if the phrase starts with and contains "Lorum * 1, 2, 3" etc

Comment: Worst case scenario, you could always go the Lua way and make a "dumbed down" version of regex that's easier to validate by hand.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo if you're going to reinvent the wheel, it's much easier to simply use one of the many libraries that do it instead, such as [Boost.Regex](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) (which you can make exception-free by setting a flag aptly named *no_except*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. There's no standard way to do it. Exceptions are an intrinsic part of the standard library, and even interfaces that don't throw their own exceptions (such as the infamous `error_code`-based interface for `<filesystem>`) can throw exceptions for other operations.

Your best bet is using a library that is designed to be exception-free, such as [Boost.Regex](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) with the `no_except` flag enabled. You can then check for errors after construction of a `boost::basic_regex`, using the member function [status](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/basic_regex.html#boost_regex.basic_regex.status).

Comment: After spending the day researching it, it seems like there is no way to do it indeed. I can't use libraries so that is out for me. I will have to abandon the idea, but will mark this as the answer unless someone else comes up with some black magic.